# Create database in parent directory

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to create a database file in the parent directory according to my working directory, so far here is what I've done

```
public void createNewDatabase(String dbName) {
    
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:..db/"+dbName)) {
        if (conn != null) {
            DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("The driver name is " + meta.getDriverName());
            System.out.println("A new database has been created.");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }       
}
```

The problem is, as you can see here `try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:..db/"+dbName))` the `DriverManager` is trying to access the directory ../db which doesn't exist.

Have you got any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: `jdbc:sqlite:..db/` shouldn't this be `jdbc:sqlite:../db/`? (notice the `/` before "db")

Comment: Still the same issue, he's trying to reach ../db :/

Comment: Are you asking how to create a new directory?  Edit the question with details of the exception.

Comment: I am asking how to create a database in the parent folder of my working directory, I don't know why, someone edited the title of my question, now it's clearer

Comment: It not clear unless you show the actual exception you get back from SQLite. The answer by @Harry Coder ought to work with url `jdbc:sqlite:../db/yourdb` unless you've not created the parent directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NIO path to validate the path for the SQLite db connection. Note that `toRealPath()` is applied to the parent to ensure the parent dir exists, before resolving the absolute pathname to the database inside the parent directory:

```
Path dbPath = Path.of("../db/yourdb");
String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlite:"+dbPath.getParent().toRealPath().resolve(dbPath.getFileName());
System.out.println("dbURL="+dbURL);

try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL)) {
...
```

or as one liner:

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlite:"+Path.of("../db").toRealPath().resolve("dbName");
```